# Jest suite doesn't output color for the snapshot diff

Tags: enzyme, jestjs, babel-jest, enzyme-to-snapshot

I just noticed on a project I'm working on that the snapshot output is not piping through colours to the terminal. The Jest framework in general *does* have colours. So I'm pretty confused:

[image]

[What it should look like](https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/2000/1*Uzyh_xxWJkTYZC3riCpHhg.png)

This is the list of relevant packages:

```
"babel-jest": "^21.0.2",
"enzyme": "^3.1.0",
"enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.0.1",
"enzyme-to-json": "^3.3.1",
```

And here is the `jest.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  setupTestFrameworkScriptFile: './setupTestFramework',
  verbose: true,
  snapshotSerializers: ['enzyme-to-json/serializer'],
  coverageReporters: [
    'lcov',
  ],
  collectCoverageFrom: [
    'src/**/*.{js,jsx}',
    'stories/**/*.{js,jsx}',
    '!**/node_modules/**',
    '!**/vendor/**',
  ],
  coverageDirectory: './',
};
```

And the `setupTestFramework` file:

```
import { configure } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import 'intersection-observer';

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

## UPDATE: works with single file

Outputs colour snapshots:

`yarn test <filepath>`

Does NOT output colour snapshots:

`yarn test`

(My `yarn test` command is `NODE_PATH=\"./src\" jest --colors`)

Comment: If you are running node 6, there is a known issue about that https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/5431

Comment: If you are running on Travis CI you have to set: `env: FORCE_COLOR=true`